# Mongoid: Criteria #find - How do I limit find to the results in the criteria?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am having some trouble understanding something with criteria and #find.

I have a bit of code that looks:

```
def returns_criteria
  MyModel.in(...)
end
```

My understanding of criteria was that the results get more restrictive as you chain things. That seems to be how relation collections work, at least, which may be misleading me.

So my expectation was that if I called:

```
returns_criteria.find(some_id)
```

then it would look for an object with id some_id within the results found by the MyModel.in call. But this is not happening, it seems like #find is called like it would be called on MyModel.

I would like to restrict this #find to the results of the currently specified criteria. Can I do this somehow?

Minimal Repro Repo: https://github.com/nchelluri/mongoid-in-find

Output of running in.rb: https://gist.github.com/nchelluri/6401850

Comment: I can't replicate the issue using Mongoid 3. Can you provide a few more details? Perhaps an example of the hash you are passing to `any_of`?

Comment: I tried to put together a minimal repro case and found that the error did not occur. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong...

Comment: It turns out I was using ::in, not ::any_of. I was able to reproduce and have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found what's going on here. If you direct Moped to log to `$stdout` you can take a closer look at what commands it's sending to the database:

```
Moped.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
Moped.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

The selector hash for the original `in` criteria object is:

```
selector={"_id"=>{"$in"=>["5222b8edf273e6eeb1000001", "5222b8edf273e6eeb1000002"]}
```

But if you chain 'find' onto it, it becomes:

```
selector={"_id"=>"5222b8edf273e6eeb1000003"}
```

...which is basically a result of the standard behavior of a Ruby hash. You've reassigned the `"_id"` key from the original `in` selector with the one from `find`. This may simply be a limitation of Mongoid/Moped, and I'm not sure how you would work around it. At the same time, I'm struggling to find a case where you would *need* to search on multiple `id` criteria, but I'll grant you that as a test case, it's a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: I actually get `selector={"_id"=>"52260b0073197f08c8000003", "$and"=>[{"_id"=>"52260b0073197f08c8000003"}]}` but otherwise I agree with you. Using `MyModel::any_of` with `:id.in` instead of `MyModel::in` with `:id` seems to achieve the desired result. Thank you for your help!

Comment: BTW, the selector with ::any_of is: `selector={"$or"=>[{"_id"=>{"$in"=>["52260ba473197f5329000001", "52260ba473197f5329000002"]}}], "_id"=>"52260ba473197f5329000003"}` .